# Can you redeclare an email header on the same line?

Tags: email, email-headers

Let's say you've got email headers like this:

```
To: john.smith@domain.com
Subject: Email Enquiry from John Smith
From: John Smith <john.smith@domain.com>
```

That all looks simple and fine. But, in this case:

```
To: john.smith@domain.com
Subject: Email Enquiry from John Smith Bcc: sendyouspam@someone.com
From: John Smith <john.smith@domain.com>
```

What would the second header be? If, on the same line, you redeclare a header, or specify a different one, will it use the first one occurring, the last one occurring, or cause an error?

I am asking, of course, for email injection reasons. If it only respects the first one then stripping user input that is used in headers of `\r`, `\n`, `%0a` and `%0d` will do the job. The reason I ask it a lot of injection code checks for to:, bcc:, cc:. I'm wondering whether that is pointless based on the above.

Answer (score 0):

The best way i to concatenate the last updated headers with your new ones.

```
$to       = "john.smith@domain.com";
$subject  = "Email Enquiry from John Smith";
$headers  = "From:John Smith <john.smith@domain.com>"."\r\n";
$headers .= "CC:sendyouspam@someone.com";
```

Comment: If, for example, the From name field is from user input could this be injected even if line returns are removed? That's essentially the question.

Comment: Of Course. You can inject the user input and concatenate by anything you want to add on the headers.

Comment: I mean can you change the header if line returns are removed rather than inject other malicious content.